# Harmonized sales tax headaches

Tags: php, codeigniter, bamboo, invoice

Alright Im using the BambooInvoice software, and where I am, we have two sales taxes.

This is how they work

price of item * tax1 = Sum1Tax1
Sum1tax1 *tax2 = Final sales price

Currently, Bamboo invoice does this

```
Price of Item * tax1 = pricetax1
price of item * tax2 = pricetax2
Price of item + pricetax1 + pricetax2
```

and this is its code

```
$this->db->select('(SELECT SUM('.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.amount * '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.quantity * ('.$this->db->dbprefix('invoices').'.tax1_rate/100 * '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.taxable)) FROM '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').' WHERE '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.invoice_id=' . $invoice_id . ') AS total_tax1', FALSE);
  $this->db->select('(SELECT SUM('.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.amount * '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.quantity * ('.$this->db->dbprefix('invoices').'.tax2_rate/100 * '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.taxable)) FROM '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').' WHERE '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.invoice_id=' . $invoice_id . ') AS total_tax2', FALSE);
  $this->db->select('(SELECT SUM('.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.amount * '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.quantity + ROUND(('.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.amount * '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.quantity * ('.$this->db->dbprefix('invoices').'.tax1_rate/100 + '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoices').'.tax2_rate/100) * '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.taxable), 2)) FROM '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').' WHERE '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.invoice_id=' . $invoice_id . ') AS total_with_tax', FALSE);
```

How would we modify this code to reflect the actual taxation scheme for my area?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built in invoice settings to change the taxes. If you insist on hard coding it. You could do something like this:

```
<?php 
$customTaxRate_1 = 15;
$customTaxRate_2 = 25; //Norwegian sales tax phew :( But free health care :)
$this->db->select('(SELECT SUM('.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.amount * '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.quantity * ('.$this->db->dbprefix('invoices').'.'.$customTaxRate_1.'/100 * '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.taxable)) FROM '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').' WHERE '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.invoice_id=' . $invoice_id . ') AS total_tax1', FALSE);
$this->db->select('(SELECT SUM('.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.amount * '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.quantity * ('.$this->db->dbprefix('invoices').'.'.$customTaxRate_2.'/100 * '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.taxable)) FROM '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').' WHERE '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.invoice_id=' . $invoice_id . ') AS total_tax2', FALSE);
$this->db->select('(SELECT SUM('.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.amount * '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.quantity + ROUND(('.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.amount * '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.quantity * ('.$this->db->dbprefix('invoices').'.'.$customTaxRate_1.'/100 + '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoices').'.'.$customTaxRate_2.'/100) * '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.taxable), 2)) FROM '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').' WHERE '.$this->db->dbprefix('invoice_items').'.invoice_id=' . $invoice_id . ') AS total_with_tax', FALSE);
?>
```

Please make sure to test properly. I am not familiar with the software. And my answer is based on the code you provided.